# how to call external function inside onAuthorize in paypal angular 4

Tags: angular, paypal

In below code I am getting `Cannot read property 'http' of undefined` is undefined.
How can I call an external custom function inside onAuthorize function.

This is the link from where I have taken help https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client
your any help will be appreciable.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const total = this.total_amount;
    const selected_package = this.selected_package.name;
    this.loadExternalScript('https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js').then(() => {
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox',
            client: {
                production: '',
                sandbox: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            },
            commit: true,
            payment: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: total, currency: 'USD' },
                                description: selected_package,
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                })
            },
            onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function (payment) {
                    const formdata: FormData = new FormData;
                    formdata.append('Payment[trns_id]', payment.id);
                    formdata.append('Payment[paypal]', payment);
                    formdata.append('Payment[amount]', payment.transactions[0].amount);
                    formdata.append('Payment[order_id]', order_id);
                    formdata.append('Payment[state]', payment.state);
                    formdata.append('Payment[auth_token]', auth_token);
                    this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'orders/paypal-checkout', formdata).subscribe(
                        (result) => {
                            this.responceData = result.json();
                            if (this.responceData.data.status === true && this.responceData.data.status_message === 'success') {
                                this.router.navigateByUrl('/questionnaire/successfully');
                            }
                        },
                        (err) => {
                            console.log('Error' + err);
                        })
                })
            },
            onError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }, '#paypal-button');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `function` keyword creates new scope and changes the value of `this`. You need to use
lambda functions which do not change the value of `this` like below:

You just need to replace `function (data, actions)` with `(data, actions) =>` and
`function(payment)` with `(payment) =>` and not anything else

```
onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
    return actions.payment.execute().then((payment) => {
```

Comment: U r welcome khurshed. Can u pls accept the answer if u are satisfied ?